# Does a non deterministic Turing machine which is a decider halt on all branches for all inputs?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, nondeterminism

Does a non deterministic Turing machine which is a decider halt on all branches for all inputs??

I know it must halt on all branches for a string not in language, but for a string in language, NDTM requires only one accepting branch so even if some other branch is infinite, NDTM will still accept the string

Answer (score 4):

You can define it either way.  The simple way to  define it is to say that *every* branch must halt for every input.  Alternatively, you can say that, if the input is in the language, at least one branch must accept, so you don't care if the others reject or just fail to halt; if the input is not in the language, then every branch must reject.

Both in terms of computability and complexity, you can show that the two definitions are completely equivalent.

Comment: I'm not so sure those will be equivalent in terms of complexity. ​ For example, suppose a language is decidable by a NDTM such that, when it accepts, at least one branch does so in 2^([o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)(n)) steps. ​ Is it known to follow that the language is decidable by a NDTM whose paths _all_ halt in 2^([o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)(n)) steps? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes, that's known. As long as the function $f$ giving the bound is time-constructible, you can ensure that every branch halts in the required bound by first computing $f$ and then having every branch that hasn't already halted after $f$ steps halt and reject.

Comment: Why would there necessarily be a time-constructible function in 2^(o(n)) that bounds the lengths of minimal-length accepting paths? ​ ​