# Confused about the concept of deciding in nondeterministic Turing machines

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability, computation-models, nondeterminism

I read [this discussion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142007/confused-about-definition-of-a-non-deterministic-decider) before.
However i’m still confused. I used to think a language decided by a NTM if for every input $w$ in $\Sigma^*$, all of the branches in computation tree leads to a halting configuration, and $w \in L$ iff there exists an accepting path in its computation tree.

But because me and the student who asked [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142007/confused-about-definition-of-a-non-deterministic-decider) (with a nickname) studying in the same university, there is an alternative definition  for decider NTM in our university which confused us. These are the definitions:

> The computation trees of deciders are complementry with respect to the answers “Accept” and “Reject”. … if $w \in L$ and $M$ is a NTM *decider* then in computation tree, there is some accepting branch and there is ***No*** rejecting branch. We may have loop or crash branch too. And if $w \notin L$ then in computation tree, there is some rejecting branch and there is no accepting branch. We may have loop or crash branch too.
>
> Crash barnch: Computation path which the last  node is a halting configuration which its state is not $q_{accept}$ or $q_{reject}$.
>
> Loop branch: Infinite computation path.

And there is another type of NTM, which is called NTM *acceptor*:

> If $w \in L$ and $M$ is a NTM *acceptor* then in computation tree, there is some accepting branch. And if $w \notin L$ there is no accepting branch.

The definition of acceptor is natrual to me. But because in refrences which i read before there is a contradiction in definition of deciders, i am so confused and i am really curious which sources define deciders and acceptors like the definitions above.

Comment: I have never seen a nondeterministic Turing machine that decides a language being "defined" as your first quote. Also, it's unclear what a loop or crash branch is (notice that a computation can go on forever without repeating any configuration of the machine). A nondetermistic Turing machine $T$ accepts a word $w$ if there exists a computation path for which $T$ with input $w$ halts and accepts. $T$ rejects $w$ if none of the computation paths accept (i.e., they are either infinite, or they reject).

Comment: @Steven I read five different sources and i did not see any definitions like this. Also i edited my question and defined crash and loop branch.

Comment: In the definitions that I have seen, the only way for a (decider) TM to halt is to reach either the accepting or the rejecting state. Here is a source: [Bovet, Crescenzi. Introduction to the theory of complexity](https://www.diag.uniroma1.it//~ausiello/InfoTeoIIRM/book/itc.pdf).

Comment: Here is [an answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/54488/91753) to a related question, [does a non deterministic Turing machine which is a decider halt on all branches for all inputs?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54486/does-a-non-deterministic-turing-machine-which-is-a-decider-halt-on-all-branches)